# How to save an option in a dropdown menu as a php session variable?

Tags: php, session, drop-down-menu

I am trying to save one of the options in a dropdown menu as a session variable.

```
<select name="number" id="number">
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
            <option>three</option>
        </select>

            <?php
         session_start();
$_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];
?>
```

What it returns in the browser page is:

> Notice: Undefined index: number in
>   C:\xampp-portable\htdocs\eva\00ideaselection.php on line 46

1. What is the error here?
2. What is the best way to save an option from a dropdown menu as session variable?

Comment: Seems like your `$_POST` doesn't have the `number` index. Recheck that. There isn't enough code here to debug it.

Comment: You are trying to access a POST parameter before even _submitting_ the form and thereby sending any POST data … look up `isset`/`empty` in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<select name="number" id="number">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>three</option>
    </select>

   <?php
     session_start();
     if(isset($_POST['number']))
         $_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];
  ?>
```

The error you see is because you have not posted the form and you are trying to get the value from $_POST. The $_POST and $_GET has data from posted form.  So when you are posting your form to same php script where the form is created, then when the form is loaded without form post, it will show you that notice message. To avoid notice message, i place an

```
   isset($_POST['number'])
```

check, this way no notice will be shown.

When the form is posted, and you get $_POST, then the value will be set into session.

Thanks

Comment: It worked. The reason, it did not work, was that I had put both php and html patches in the same file. I created another one and via a form I called the php file.

Answer (score 2):

Add `value` to the drop down

```
<select name="number" id="number">
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
      <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

and while retriving the value use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function to check whether the value has been posted

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['number'])){
        $_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: It worked both with value or not. If I don't put the value attribute it will save the text at the session.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="number" id="number">
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
      <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

while retriving the value use empty() function to check whether the value has been posted and is not empty. isset() not checks as numbers are passed as an argument in $_POST as string

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_POST['number'])){
        $_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];
    }
 ?>
```